# Conversion failed varchar to data type int

Tags: sql

I'm new at `SQL` and i cant find out what im doing wrong, my query looks logic but it doesn't convert my `INT_VALUE` TO `VARCHAR_VALUE`. I dont want to use `ALTER` cause its needs to stay a INT value and i want to give a name on  int values.

```
-- BEGIN

SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN COLUMN_NAME = INT_VALUE THEN 'VARCHAR_VALUE'
ELSE COLUMN_NAME END)AS VARCHAR(15)) FROM TABLE_NAME 

-- END
```

I did try with `CONVERT` aswell but i got the same error, please explain why
i get this error cause it looks very logical for me.
Thanks Advanced.

Comment: What is the data type of `COLUMN_NAME`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `column_name` is an int column, you can do this.

```
Select
    case column_name 
        when int_value then 'varchar_value'
        else cast(column_name as varchar(15))
    end
from
    table_name
```

All the branches of a case statement must return the same data type.